# Can't install nodejs on Ubuntu 22.04 using raspberry pi

Tags: node.js

sudo apt install nodejs results in the following output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/25.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 123 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 190541 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:arm64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm a newbee so any help is appreciated

Comment: Generally you want to install node on \*n\*x using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating), not apt/yum/pacman/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's recommended to install `nvm` instead of node directly.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

```
nvm list-remote
```

Then install the version of node you want

e.g.

```
nvm install v14.10.0
```

Take a look here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04